# Android 4.14 kernel not exporting all headers

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I'm trying to export my android kernel headers to build tracee against it but I can't get all the headers correctly exported and the make for the project I'm building against.

```
<built-in>:1:10: fatal error: '../headers/include/linux/kconfig.h' file not found

include "/headers/headers/include/linux/kconfig.h"
```

Kernel source is at https://github.com/nitanmarcel/android_kernel_xiaomi_sm6250-ebpf

Here's the output of `make headers_install ARCH=arm64 O=OUT` I also tried generating the headers in both the kernel dir and build dir and merging them but it doesn't fix the issue

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nitanmarcel/android_kernel_xiaomi_sm6250-lost/out'
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  INSTALL include/asm-generic (36 files)
  INSTALL include/drm (27 files)
  INSTALL include/linux (533 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/android (2 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/byteorder (2 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/caif (2 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/can (6 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/cifs (1 file)
  INSTALL include/linux/dvb (8 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/genwqe (1 file)
  INSTALL include/linux/hdlc (1 file)
  INSTALL include/linux/hsi (2 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/iio (2 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/isdn (1 file)
  INSTALL include/linux/mmc (3 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/netfilter (88 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/netfilter/ipset (4 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/netfilter_arp (2 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/netfilter_bridge (17 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/netfilter_ipv4 (10 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/netfilter_ipv6 (12 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/nfc (2 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/nfsd (5 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/raid (2 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/sched (1 file)
  INSTALL include/linux/spi (1 file)
  INSTALL include/linux/sunrpc (1 file)
  INSTALL include/linux/tc_act (15 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/tc_ematch (4 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/usb (16 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/wimax (1 file)
  INSTALL include/media (34 files)
  INSTALL include/misc (1 file)
  INSTALL include/mtd (5 files)
  INSTALL include/rdma (20 files)
  INSTALL include/rdma/hfi (2 files)
  INSTALL include/scsi (6 files)
  INSTALL include/scsi/fc (4 files)
  INSTALL include/scsi/ufs (2 files)
  INSTALL include/sound (15 files)
  INSTALL include/video (5 files)
  INSTALL include/xen (4 files)
  INSTALL include/asm (35 files)
  INSTALL techpack/audio/include/linux (19 files)
  INSTALL techpack/audio/include/linux/mfd (0 file)
  INSTALL techpack/audio/include/linux/mfd/wcd9xxx (2 files)
  INSTALL techpack/audio/include/sound (7 files)
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nitanmarcel/android_kernel_xiaomi_sm6250-lost/out'
```